# Can't boot my laptop

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

My laptop was running both Windows 7 Home Premium and Ubuntu 12.10. I decided to uninstall Windows 7 with OS-Uninstaller. I didn't remember that my Ubuntu was installed with Wubi and when I uninstalled Windows 7, I also lost Wubi. Now I can't boot my laptop. I also thought I could install Ubuntu on an USB, but my laptop is unable to boot from USB. How can I fix this?

Comment: Right now, it seems that the only way to fix this is start back from square one and hope that you backed everything up...

Comment: Which I didn't do. Oh well, it was a pretty old laptop and I was going to get a new one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootable Ubuntu disc and install using that http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. It will work pretty much the same way as installing from a live USB.

Comment: The laptop doesn't have a disc tray

Answer (score 0):

When you turn your computer on there should be a short window of opportunity to access the BIOS menu. This is where you can change the boot priority of your computer. Usually the CD drive is the highest priority which is why an install disk is booted when it's in the tray on startup. The USB drive is often listed as a lower priority than the main hard drive which is why you probably can't boot from USB.

That said, I'd recommend installing from a CD/DVD. It is a lot more reliable and there is a lot less quirkiness involved.

Comment: I don't know why, but  I just can't boot from USB. I go to the BIOS menu, change the priority to USB, reboot the laptop but still it doesn't boot. I could install from CD, but it's a mini laptop so it doesn't have the CD/DVD tray.